# Android Custom Content View

Tags: java, android, xml

I've made a custom layoutView instead of a built in xml that comes with each Android activity. So onCreate in my MainActivity I've set:

```
    setContentView(mainActivity_layoutView);
```

mainActivity_layoutView is my custom layout java class. I made that layout so I could do my own custom animations. Now here is the question:
Since mainActivity_layoutView is a java class, how do I add a button to my custom layout? Typically if you are referencing the xml file, you would just add this line "button.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);", but I am not using the xml file, I'm using my custom java class, so how would I go about adding a button to it? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Button");
mainActivity_layoutView.addView(btn);
```

That should do it.

Comment: Nope.. You're calling a method in mainActivity_layoutView that doesn't exits, and passing the btn object. That does not work.

Comment: What does your custom layout implement/extend?

Comment: extends SurfaceView implements Runnable

Comment: ah... you will need to create an "addView" function that adds the view to your view. This may help: http://jwlstudios.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-add-button-to-surfaceview-in.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link. Got it to work now. One more thing if you got any suggestion on: From that tutorial how would I set the x and y location on the screen for my button?

Comment: You could in the layout params align it to whichever sides and then add a margin of whatever offset you would like^^ Or you could use an AbsoluteLayout instead of a RelativeLayout but you have to watch out for different size screens so I would stick with the Relative if possible!